# Seamless overlapping in procedural material

Tags: materials, shader-nodes, procedural

I'm currently developing a procedural art material. A combination of slate and gold. So far the design is good, but what I can't do is to bring the three different gold materials together, - overlapping invisibly - one should not see the intersections, as if it were only one single gold material. (The HEX CODE is identical)
I have tried all the options of the color mix node - "add", "multiply" etc., but there are always seams. Does anyone know how to make the transition continuous? Thx

[image: preview]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be better to work with the *Ornament* node group as a mask for mixing shaders (gold / stone material) ... (*Factors* are 1, plus last *Color Mix* node enable *Clamp Result*)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and thx for your Answer - when i tried it the first time i set the Color Mix Node to "Mix" and Stripes disappears - but with "ADD" it is perfect. Thanks for your help :)